# Excel 2016 filter

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have an Excel 2016 spreadsheet and I have added basic filters to the column headers. Is there a way to number the rows, but NOT have the numbers change when the filters are used? For example, I have 47 rows of data...if you select one of the filters and it results in only 10 rows of data showing, I want to see the rows numbered 1, 2, 3, etc. - I don't want the numbers to be affected by the use of the filter.

Comment: Are you trying to reference these numbers in a formula?

Comment: No - I want users to select a filter but have the numbers remain static as they represent the order that tasks need to be completed

Answer (score 1):

Create a Column at the left of your Data for the numbers include it wit the Filter and use this formula under the Header:

`=SUBTOTAL(103,$B$2:B2)`
supposing B2 is the First Data before applying the filter and drag it down the column, then apply your criteria it will show 1,2,3...